# How do I implement iOS Native Twitter loing with Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, parse-platform

How do I implement Native Twitter login on Parse.com? If the user has the App and is logged in on the device in iOS settings, I'd like to use that native session.

I've tried:

```
[PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) { 
    // This opens a Safari Browser session
}];
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else wondering (I haven't confirmed yet, myself) but according to the most recent Parse.com changelogs, the framework as of 4/4/14 implements Native Twitter login:

https://parse.com/docs/downloads

v1.2.19 — April 4, 2014

PFTwitterUtils now supports system Twitter accounts (SSO). The following dependencies should be added to Xcode projects that use PFTwitterUtils: